# Insert in room in android only if name not present

Tags: android, android-room

I have been trying to make an app where I store a list of names using room. I want to add a name only when the name is not already present. and if it is present I want to update the existing data associated with that name.
Can someone please help me in doing that.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within your DAO where you annotate the methods, that you call to perform database actions

If you annotate with

```
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
```

it will check if the entry already exists (by primary key) and update the row with the information you're trying to persist.